# D-domain vs Time-domain (Digital Linear sequential ciruits)

Tags: digital-logic, linear

I wonder if anyone could give my a short explanation of the D-domain and T-domain in linear sequential digital ciruits.
Got an exam in about 3 weeks. Last chapter is very theoretical. I got a hard time visualizing why I should use the D-domain. I can calculate it but I have no clue if someone asks me....."why do you use this"?

To those people telling me to ask the prof. and his minions : They are all on X-mas-leave

Formal question:
What is the purpose of the D-domain? What is the diffrence between D and T-domain?

EDIT:
Accordning to my book; D-domain is a domain where you are calculating with delay-operators.
In other words; the use the Huffman D-transform. 
They are talking about "The delay of a Laurent series" and so on...
[image: Example D-transform]

[image: Example D-transform]

Comment: Where are you getting this D domain information? I've never heard of it, and none of my books mention it.

Answer (score 1):

There are two applications that I know of specifically (although I'm sure there are many more):

1. Linear feedback shift register analysis.  This would directly use the form you have in the question, i.e. XORs with a stream of bits.  LFSRs are used to implement CRC in hardware or to provide non-cryptographic pseudorandom sequences.
2. If you widen the notation to mean addition instead of XOR and allow each x value to have more than one bit of information, it is effectively equivalent to a z-transform.   Z-transforms are used in all sorts of digital signal processing applications, such as digital filters and correlators.